# How to ignore gradle build of root project for a multi-project Kotlin Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, gradle-multi-project-build

**Background:**

I currently have a multi-module (multi-project) application repo. The "root" is **not** a runnable application. It's merely the source directory where I have a root `build.gradle.kts` file which holds the dependencies and plugins that are common between all my sub-projects. Each of my sub-projects have their own `build.gradle.kts`.

So my overall project structure looks sort of like this:

```
my_root_project
    - gradle
        - wrapper
            - gradle-wrapper.jar
            - gradle-wrapper.properties
    - gradle.build.kts
    - settings.gradle.kts
    - my_nested_project_a
        - src
            - main
                - kotlin
    - my_nested_project_b
        ...
```

**Issue:**

Every time I run `gradle build`, I get an error saying:

```
> Task :bootJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved
```

However when I run any one of my sub-projects (e.g. `build :my_nested_project_a:build`), it builds just fine.

**Current Gradle Build Files**

Here's what I currently have in the "root" `gradle.build.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.8.RELEASE" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.3.50"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven(url = "https://my.company.com/repo/with/all/the/stuff/I/need")
    }

    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")
    apply(plugin = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
```

> NOTE: I'm using `apply false` on my plugins because I thought it would keep gradle from trying to find a main class when building using `gradle build`.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a CI pipeline that I'd like to simply run `gradle build` which should run the `build` task for all of the sub-projects. However, in that process, I'd like to ignore running the build for the "root" project or bypass it since it's not a runnable application, and just build the sub-projects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore task `bootJar`,s o add the following configuration.

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Gradle, so forgive me if I'm asking the obvious. Is this Kotlin DSL syntax? Also, I tried adding it to my root `gradle.build.kts` file (outside of any other tasks), but I got compilation errors. Is there a specific place I should be putting it?

Comment: could you please take a look this example project https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/blob/master/samples/hello-android/build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 1):

In your root `build.gradle.kts`, ignore  `bootJar` task, with **Kotlin DSL** :

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the plugin applied in `allprojects` session, you're applying it to the root as well, and since it's the first one resolved in `gradle build`, you should have the main class configured there.

Alternatively, you can remove the `apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")` line from the root and apply the plugin only to the module that has the `main` method annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, and point the plugin to the main class there.

Say your main class is in `my_nested_project_a/src/main/com/example/MainClass.kt`.

Your `my_nested_project_a/build.gradle.kts` should look like:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.example.MainClass"
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

And you should remove this line from the root `build.gradle.kts`:

```
apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and question. I replaced `allprojects` with `subprojects` and added `jar.enabled(false)` to the root build.gradle file and it worked.

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id('org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm') version "${kotlinVersion}"
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "${spotlessVersion}"
    id("maven-publish")
}

jar.enabled(false)

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
    apply plugin: "com.diffplug.spotless"
    apply plugin: "maven-publish"

    group = GROUP
    version = VERSION_NAME

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:${junitVersion}")
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            library(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://gitlab.mhighpoint.com/api/v4/projects/${System.getenv('CI_PROJECT_ID')}/packages/maven"
                credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                    name = "Job-Token"
                    value = System.getenv('CI_JOB_TOKEN')
                }
                authentication {
                    header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    spotless {
        java {
            googleJavaFormat() // googleJavaFormat('1.1') to specify a specific version
        }
        kotlin {
            target '**/src/**/*.kt'
            ktlint("0.41.0").userData('disabled_rules': 'no-wildcard-imports,import-ordering')

            trimTrailingWhitespace()
            indentWithSpaces()
            endWithNewline()
        }
        format 'misc', {
            target '**/*.gradle'

            trimTrailingWhitespace()
            indentWithSpaces() // or spaces. Takes an integer argument if you don't like 4
            endWithNewline()
        }
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    jar {
        archiveBaseName = "${rootProject.name}-${project.name}"
    }

    tasks {
        assemble.dependsOn(spotlessApply)
    }
}
```